# Issues in fuzzing parameters on a website and search for cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities

Tags: xss, owasp, fuzzing

I am using OWASP's Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP) to fuzz parameters on a website and search for cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. After looking at a youtube video "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmbi-VbIK6I", I am trying to implement it, but while fuzzing, I have received only few response as compared to that video. Scripts are not displayed. Above all, how to identify that which script hits by looking at the response code? I am very new to this field. I am posting screenshots to see the difference. Please help me out.

My Output :
[image: My Output]
Vids Output:
[image: Vids Output]

Comment: Which version of ZAP are you using? And what is the size of your xss-rsnake.txt file?